# How can I solve the issue of having disk already full?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, data-science, putty

Currently i'm learning big data using aws through an online course, I am going through an issue of disk already full and cannot install anaconda in it.

I even increased the volume of my ec2 instance but to no effect as 100% of the disk is used
I have tried to install anaconda in 2 difference locations on the root computer as it did not work the first time, and now i'm stuck

```
 Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            481M     0  481M   0% /dev
tmpfs            99M   11M   88M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop0       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1068
/dev/loop3       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/495
/dev/loop4       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6405
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

I want to install Anaconda and i don't have space, how can I increase the size of the disk or delete the files through putty so that i have enough space to install anaconda and other applications on the remote computer

Comment: This is not a programming problem and therefore off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you increase the size of a volume in EC2 you probably need to resize the filesystem to make use of the new space before it becomes available to you. Check out the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Comment: Well your root drive is completely full then. Better get a bigger one.

Comment: I tried every command in the above link i keep getting error like 'nothing to do' or ' disk already full'..

Comment: You need to get a bigger root drive: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/expand-root-ebs-linux/